# Zend2 - Module specific navigation

Tags: php, navigation, zend-framework2

i'm working with Zend Framework 2 and i would like to make a navigation for `Admin` module. How to do that?

Can i simply add `local.php` with navigation tree in `module/Admin/config/autoload`?

EDIT: now i have navigation in the `app-root/config/autoload/global.php`:

```
'navigation' => array(
    'default' => array(
        array(
            'label' => 'Admin home',
            'route' => 'admin',
        )
    )
)
```

and in `app-root/module/Admin/config/module.config.php`:

```
'service_manager' => array(
        'factories' => array(
            'Navigation' => 'Zend\Navigation\Service\DefaultNavigationFactory'
        )
 )
```

and in `app-root/module/Admin/view/layout/layout.phtml`:

```
<?php echo $this->navigation('navigation')->menu(); ?>
```

And everything work good, but when i cut the `navigation` array from `app-root/config/autoload/global.php` and place it in `app-root/module/Admin/config/autoload/global.php` i get an error that: `Navigation can't be initalized`.

Comment: What have you tried? What happened? What code did you write so far? Where did it fail? What's the error message?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

put the navigation config in `app-root/module/Admin/config/module.config.php`